# How can I group products and then sort them by date desc in TSQL?

Tags: sql, qtsql

Here is the SQL but it gives me an error:

```
select u.productId, count(ProductID) as total, p.Name 
from dbo.UserXProduct AS u 
INNER JOIN dbo.product AS p ON u.ProductID = p.ID   
group by productid, p.name 
having count(ProductID) > 5 
order by u.dateEntered desc, total desc
```

EDIT: Here is the error I am getting:

> Column "dbo.UserXProduct.DateEntered" is invalid in the ORDER BY
>   clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or
>   the GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 1):

You cannot order by `u.dateEntered` directly.  But, you can order by `max(u.dateEntered)`.  And this may be what you want for the most recent products:

```
select u.productId, count(ProductID) as total, p.Name 
from dbo.UserXProduct AS u 
INNER JOIN dbo.product AS p ON u.ProductID = p.ID   
group by productid, p.name 
having count(ProductID) > 5 
order by max(u.dateEntered) desc, total desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to a column alias in the `group by`. Try this instead:

```
select u.productId, count(ProductID) as total, p.Name 
from dbo.UserXProduct AS u 
INNER JOIN dbo.product AS p ON u.ProductID = p.ID   
group by productid, p.name 
having count(ProductID) > 5 
order by count(ProductID) desc
```

You cannot `ORDER BY` the u.dateEntered column unless it is present in the `group by`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. It is actually the DateEntered column which I have problem with. Here is the Error:  Column "dbo.UserXProduct.DateEntered" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Well, the problem is that if I add the DateEntered to Group by then result is not what I am expecting. All I want is the top sellers order by recent date.